# CMake cannot find curses library in MSYS2

Tags: c++, c, cmake, ncurses, msys2

CMake code segment is below

```
  find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
  include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})
  MESSAGE(STATUS "CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR is ${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

And I do have nucures installed. The header file can be found.

[search file result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOC4j.png)

However, after running `cmake .`, I got

[cmake output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ADNS.png)

```
  CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.23.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Curses (missing: CURSES_LIBRARY CURSES_INCLUDE_PATH)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.23.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.23.2/Modules/FindCurses.cmake:268 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package)
```

After using cmake in `/mingw64/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`, the cmake can pass. Successfully generate build.ninja
or makefile for mingw32.

But after running `mingw32-make` or `ninja`,I got new errors:

(basically they are about `error` and `curses.h` path)

```
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Caikera/Documents/workspace/sw/cpp/tetris/Build'
-- C:/Users/Caikera/Documents/workspace/sw/cpp/tetris
-- CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR is C:/packages/msys2/mingw64/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Caikera/Documents/workspace/sw/cpp/tetris/Build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Caikera/Documents/workspace/sw/cpp/tetris/Build'
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Caikera/Documents/workspace/sw/cpp/tetris/Build'
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Caikera/Documents/workspace/sw/cpp/tetris/Build'
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Caikera/Documents/workspace/sw/cpp/tetris/Build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tetris.dir/main.cpp.obj
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/ctime:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/chrono:42,
                 from C:\Users\Caikera\Documents\workspace\sw\cpp\tetris\main.cpp:6:
C:/packages/msys2/mingw64/include/time.h:12:2: 错误：#error Only Win32 target is supported!
   12 | #error Only Win32 target is supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from C:/packages/msys2/mingw64/include/time.h:25,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/ctime:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/chrono:42,
                 from C:\Users\Caikera\Documents\workspace\sw\cpp\tetris\main.cpp:6:
C:/packages/msys2/mingw64/include/sys/timeb.h:12:2: 错误：#error Only Win32 target is supported!
   12 | #error Only Win32 target is supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from C:/packages/msys2/mingw64/include/pthread.h:64,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-msys/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-msys/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Caikera\Documents\workspace\sw\cpp\tetris\main.cpp:8:
C:/packages/msys2/mingw64/include/sys/types.h:10:2: 错误：#error Only Win32 target is supported!
   10 | #error Only Win32 target is supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/cwctype:50,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/bits/locale_facets.h:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/ios:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Caikera\Documents\workspace\sw\cpp\tetris\main.cpp:8:
C:/packages/msys2/mingw64/include/wctype.h:10:2: 错误：#error Only Win32 target is supported!
   10 | #error Only Win32 target is supported!
      |  ^~~~~
C:\Users\Caikera\Documents\workspace\sw\cpp\tetris\main.cpp:15:10: 致命错误：curses.h：No such file or directory
   15 | #include "curses.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

[make result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGFGl.png)
[make result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlsXT.png)

Comment: you should add two lines inside your `CMakeLists.txt` file. First `set(CURSES_LIBRARY "/path/to/libncurses.so")` and then `set(CURSES_INCLUDE_PATH "/path/to/libcurl/include")`

Comment: `/usr` being mentioned in the message is suspicious. You should be running the `MINGW64` environment (as indicated by the magenta text in the terminal, not `MSYS`). Also CMake should be installed from the package called `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`, not `cmake`.

Comment: Regarding the edit: what MSYS2 environment are you using to start CMake? I.e. what's written in magenta letters in the terminal? Are you using a MSYS2 terminal in the first place?

Comment: Both "cmake ." and "make" or "ninja" is running under MSYS2 terminal.

Comment: Please use `@username` when replying in comments, otherwise I don't get notifications.

Comment: *"running under MSYS2 terminal"* Ok, but which MSYS2 environment?